# Validate phone-number format in Rails 4 - REGEX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a small project where the user should type the phone numbers, so I would like to validate that information using the "[ClientSideValidations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations)" gem.

```
validates_format_of :telcasa, :celular, :tel_flia, :tel_trab, :tel_ref_2, :tel_ref_1, 
    length: { in: 10 },
    :with => /\A(\d{10}|\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]\d{3}[-.]\d{4})\z/,
    :message => "Formato invalido"
```

But, for the region where this project is going to be used I have to validate the three first numbers of the phone that correspond to the area code ("809"/"829"/"849"). How can I validate that the user correctly typed the phone number with one of the three area codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `/\A(\d{10}|\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]\d{3}[-.]\d{4})\z/` to:

```
/\A(\(?(809|829|849)\)?[-. ]\d{3}[-.]\d{4})\z/
```

I took the liberty of dropping the part where you are matching any ten digit number - not sure why it was there or how it should be used in your context.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some custom validation

```
validate do
  valid_phone_codes = [ "007", "042", ...]
  valid_phone_codes.each do |valid_code|
    # Also handle optional parenthesis
    return true if self.phone_number.starts_with?(valid_code, "(#{valid_code})")
  end
  errors.add(:phone_numbers, "Must start with a valid country code (one of #{valid_phone_codes.join(', ')}")
  false
end
```

Or if you prefer, you can declare this code in a function `def valid_country_codes`, and then add a line

```
validate :valid_country_codes
```

Comment: The current regex includes optional parens to wrap the area code.  Not sure how that would work with this approach.

Comment: I think you can feed `starts_with?` with a regexp ?

Comment: Hmm no you can't, however, [you can feed many arguments to start_with?](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/start_with%3F), I'll update the code